# How can I get the transparency right when layering pictureboxes?

Tags: c#

In my setup i have 5 pictureboxes which I am trying to layer.

My code for this is:

```
            pbCoin1.Parent = pbMap;
            pbCoin1.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
            pbCoin2.Parent = pbMap;
            pbCoin2.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
            pbCoin3.Parent = pbMap;
            pbCoin3.BackColor = Color.Transparent;

            pbFlashlight.Parent = pbMap;
            pbFlashlight.BackColor = Color.Transparent;`
```

All 5 pictureboxes contain images. The method I am using works fine, but the problem is that the PbCoin 1,2,3 are glitching trough my pbFLashlight(see image).

Can someone provide a solution such that the coins are only visible when the transparent part of the black layer is over it?

[image: Link to image]

Comment: WinForms?  Transparency won't work as you want it to.

Comment: Yes its WinForms, but then why its the backlayer showing the bottom layer, so that tranparency is working. But the 3 coins are glitching like this? Is it WinForms?

Comment: WinForms does not properly support transparency.  Your best option is to use WPF.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use multiple picture boxes.  Use a single PictureBox to represent the game area and handle the `.Paint` event.  Do all of your drawing using GDI calls on the `Graphics` reference that `.Paint` sends you in `e`.  You will want to call `PictureBox.Invalidate` at the end of the Paint event to cause it to queue up the next frame

For better performance, create a new `Bitmap` instance that you keep a reference to for the life of the game.  Clear and do all your drawing to that bitmap every frame, then draw that bitmap to the PictureBox in `.Paint`.

For even better performance than that, don't use WinForms.

The basic pattern should look like this:

```
private void Canvas_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    e.Graphics.DrawImage(...);

    Canvas.Invalidate();
}
```

Comment: i've tried this, but when i try doin it this way, my form just goes grey and then closes on its own...

Comment: Are you calling `.Paint` manually inside `.Paint`?  If so, don't, that will lock up the application.  you need to use `.Invalidate` to make Windows queue up the next update without strangling the message pump.

Comment: Im just adding a paint event to my picturebox, and then have picturebox_paint(etc, etc), this does lock up my application

Comment: You should never have to manually call Paint.  See my update above.

Comment: If it continues to lock up, post more code.  I've used this pattern many times for simple games without issue.

Comment: even with using this.invalidate, or picturebox.invalidate it still just locksup an cloes on its own

Comment: _it still just locksup an cloes on its own_ SO? You must not call invalidate in or trigger it from the paint event..

Comment: ohh my.  that will lock things up like crazy.  Don't load your image every time. load it once in the form's `.Load` event.  keep the variable as a form level variable.  Just do draw and invalidate in the paint event.

Comment: @Bradley: The basic pattern in your answer is quite __wrong__! Never call invalidate from the paint, call it instead!

Comment: @TaW It is perfectly acceptable to call .Invalidate from inside .Paint. All it does it mark the control as "dirty" and will trigger a repaint the next time the app is idle.

Comment: Im not calling invalidate in the paint event

Comment: The answer does and it will cause an __infinite loop and lock and crash__ the program.

Comment: Might sound pretty noob, but isnt it a void event, like Private Void Paintevent?

Comment: @BramSnoek You are correct, I'm doing this without the benefit of Visual Studio being open.

Comment: I put a breakpoint at the Paint event, once i allow it to run the event, the application just locks up and closes, ive tried returning, breaking, invalidatiing etc. Idk why its still locking up

Comment: what is the last line to execute before it locks up?

Comment: The last line it executes, is application.run(frmcontroller);

Comment: And when  it runs Pbmap_paint it locks uop